# Integration of azure ad sdk within cordova app

Tags: cordova, mobile, azure-active-directory, adal

How to integrate Azure AD SDK within the mobile application build in cordova. I have gone through various articles about Azure AD. But still have some doubts like , whether the app's login page will be replaced by the authentication page provided by azure ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the ADAL.js GitHub page - it has link to samples and docs
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

You may want to install and run this sample to better understand how the SDK works: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/

Here is a library specifically for Cordova: 
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova

Please ask for more clarification on GitHub, via the issues page.

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan for providing these useful links.But still i have a confusion.I m a newbie for ionic cordova apps.I got a requirement to integrate azure Ad in the app.But the app is already using some other thing for SSO , is there anything else which Azure AD will provide for the app.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the Cordova lib.

Comment: @BogdanGavrilMSFT whats the proposed solution for integrating Azure AD into Cordova now since the Plugin has been deprecated?